# Large gradient magnitude in WGAN-GP

Tags: machine-learning, gan, wasserstein

I've implemented a minimal WGAN-GP on MNIST ([code here](https://gist.github.com/ahrzb/03a804ce3b74d7173b18771b250d2114)).it kinda works and outputs some digits but loss/gradient magnitudes are so huge, for example:

- $GradientPenalty \approx 10^{19}$
- $D(\hat{x})- D(x) \approx -10^{10}$
- $-D(\hat{x}) \approx 10^{10}$

There is definitely something wrong with these numbers, but I've got no clues, have you any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Guess what? when you do a backward pass on results of `autograd.grad` you should pass `create_graph=True`.

> create_graph (bool, optional) – If True, graph of the derivative will be constructed, allowing to compute higher order derivative products. Defaults to False.